# Push in intellij 12/13 in GIT is not working

Tags: git, intellij-idea, push

In intellij 12 and 13 I tried pushing using GIT and it is not working. 
THere is no error as such displayed but the status shows as pushing until you restart idea.
I investigated issue a bit and found that Idea fires

```
git push --progress orgin master:master
```

I tried same command from command and it didn't work. Then I tried

```
git push -u orgin master:master
```

and it worked. 
It seems that Intellij idea has bug in pushing but work around is commit from intellij and push from command prompt. 
My question is 
1. is there a way to change git command in intellij so that I would change it to the second one?
2. Is there any work around of the problem other than what i faced?

Note: I don't get any error or exception but it keeps pushing..

Comment: 1. yes, submit a patch! 2. wait for 13.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out be issue with config file in ".git" folder. 
The pushUrl key's U was in small case :-|
When I change it to caps it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried push in 13 and worked ok, this is output

```
git push --progress origin master:master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 617 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /path/to/my/repo/
   c5d1420..e6e67d5  master -> master
```

Are you sure you have all references and upstream branch right? Is the **orgin** a typo in your post??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out, that the bug is not in intellijidea, ​​it is in the Git.
You may download: `Git-1.9.4-preview20140611`.
From https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/,

and then set the config in bash

```
git config --global sendpack.sideband false
```

or for older versions of git, use this tutorial 
http://weberde.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/how-to-fix-windows-7-64-bit-git-push-msysgit-hang-up-problem/